# Are OSQLAsynchQuery and OSQLNonBlockingQuery still relevant in Orient 3.0?

Tags: java, nosql, orientdb, graph-databases

In Orient 3.0, the recommended querying mechanism via multi-model API is the set of query/execute/command methods that always take in "strings" as queries. How would we go about executing OSQLAsynchQuery and OSQLNonBlockingQuery type queries in the new 3.0 multi-model API without resorting to deprecated methods?

Comment: Did you already took a look at this? http://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/java/Java-API.html#multi-model-api Hope it helps

Comment: @MichelaBonizzi Yes, I looked at the docs earlier - this is easy enough to do using the older APIs, but the new multi-model API does not seem to have a way to do the same thing.